# this expression was expected to have type IDataReader but here has type SqlDataReader

Tags: f#, upcasting, idatareader

The following code is not casting my return value of `SqlDataReader` from `getReader` correctly to `IDataReader`in the call to `Seq.unfold`. **What am I doing wrong?**

```
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient
open System.Configuration

type Foo = { id:int; name:string }

let populateFoo (r:IDataReader) =
    let o = r.GetOrdinal
    { id = o "id" |> r.GetInt32; name = o "name" |> r.GetString; }

let iter populateObject (r:IDataReader)  =
    match r.Read() with
    | true -> Some(populateObject r, r)
    | _    -> None

let iterFoo = iter populateFoo

let getReader : IDataReader =
    let cnstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.["db"].ConnectionString
    let cn = new SqlConnection(cnstr)
    let cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Foo", cn)
    cmd.ExecuteReader()

let foos = Seq.unfold iterFoo getReader
```

Comment: I don't know F# at all but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx#code-snippet-4) says `Upcasting is applied automatically when you pass arguments to methods on an object type. However, for let-bound functions in a module, upcasting is not automatic, unless the parameter type is declared as a flexible type.`. So maybe `populateFoo (r:#IDataReader)` will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# does not automatic upcasting like C#, except in some specific scenarios (see the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html), section 14.4.2).

You have to explicitly cast the expression: `cmd.ExecuteReader() :> IDataReader` then you can remove the type annotation after `getReader`.

Alternatively you may leave that function returning an `SqlDataReader` and upcast at the call site:

```
let foos = getReader :> IDataReader |> Seq.unfold iterFoo
```

If `unfold` was a static member of a type with a signature like this one:

```
type T() =
    static member unfold(a, b:IDataReader) = Seq.unfold a b
```

you would be able to do directly `T.unfold(iterFoo, getReader)` and it will automatically upcast. That's one of the cases mentioned in the spec.

Comment: After reading 14.4.2, am I understanding correctly that Seq.unfold is the source of the problem and that because of it's type signature `(('a -> ('b * 'a) option) -> 'a -> seq<'b>)` it cannot determine if the type of `'a` is `IDataReader` or `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: @CharlesLambert Exactly, it does not fit in the cases mentioned by the spec. I add to the answer an hypothetical example where it would do the upcast for you.

Comment: you wouldn't have to do `unfold(a, b:#IDataReader)`?

Comment: @CharlesLambert No, since it's a member of a type a flexible type annotation will not be needed. Yes I know, those rules are a bit hard to remember, better have the spec at hand in these cases.

Comment: couldn't you in this case do  `>| upcast` [without a type] as the function has had a return type spec'd in the signature

Comment: @RubenBartelink Yes, that's yet another solution, you can upcast in the last line of the function. But on the left side of the expression, I mean without the `|>` since `upcast` is not a first-class value.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Methinks my F# is getting rusy due o lack of recent use. Need to fix that :)